# In my scala function, why am I getting error - "type mismatch; found : Unit required: Int"?

Tags: scala

Here is the definition of my code:

```
val sdf: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
val cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

def get_end(event_end_dtm : ListBuffer[String], window_start: String, window_stop: String): Int = {
      var i = 0;
      
      for (i <- event_end_dtm.indexOf(window_start) until event_end_dtm.length){
        if(sdf.parse(event_end_dtm(i)).compareTo(sdf.parse(window_stop)) > 0){
          println( "Value of i: " + i )         
          return i-1
        } 
        
      }
     
    }
```

When I am trying to run the code I am getting the below error:

```
type mismatch; found : Unit required: Int
```

I am very new to scala, hence if someone can please provide some help on this one, will really appreciate that.

Comment: I looked up some SO answer related to the same error, but I am not much able to grasp the answers there!

Comment: Because you require to return an `Int` and you never return anything if the condition of the `if` statement is never triggered.

Answer (score 4):

`get_end` doesn't return anything explicitly if the `if` never triggers. You need to decide what you want to do in that case. Most commonly, you'd return an `Option`.

```
def get_end(event_end_dtm : ListBuffer[String], window_start: String, window_stop: String): Option[Int] = {
  var i = 0;
  for (i <- event_end_dtm.indexOf(window_start) until event_end_dtm.length){
    if(sdf.parse(event_end_dtm(i)).compareTo(sdf.parse(window_stop)) > 0){
      println( "Value of i: " + i )         
      return Some(i-1)
    } 
  }
  // Oops, didn't find it; return nothing
  None
}
```

If you're quite certain the value should exist, you can always explicitly throw an exception after the fact, instead. But this is generally a less favorable approach than letting the caller decide what to do.

```
def get_end(event_end_dtm : ListBuffer[String], window_start: String, window_stop: String): Int = {
  var i = 0;
  for (i <- event_end_dtm.indexOf(window_start) until event_end_dtm.length){
    if(sdf.parse(event_end_dtm(i)).compareTo(sdf.parse(window_stop)) > 0){
      println( "Value of i: " + i )         
      return i-1
    } 
  }
  // Oops, didn't find it; commence panicking
  throw new RuntimeError("Couldn't find the value! :(")
}
```

Comment: I would also add a more _"functional"_ version using `foldLeft` or `zip` + `collectFirst`